# How can I quote a play from the middle of a line?

Tags: shakespeare

Here is the play stanza:

> Good night to everyone. [To Brabantio] And, noble
>
> signior,
>
> If virtue no delighted beauty lack,
>
> Your son-in-law is far more fair than black.

I do not need this part, "Good night to everyone. [To Brabantio]." Should I just use an ellipsis to start the line from the middle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ellipsis is necessary. The convention is that the partial line is indented substantially—enough to show that it is in fact a partial line:

> And, noble signior,
>   If virtue no delighted beauty lack,
>   Your son-in-law is far more fair than black.